# Binding ContentControl to ViewModel and preserving that VM in the View associated with.

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I am creating a WP8 application where I am binding contentcontrol to ViewModel. This ContentControl takes the DataTemplate specified in App.xaml.cs for that VM and bind to the contentcontrol template. But the problem is that I am not able to get the instance of that VM in my View. How can I get or pass my VM instance to my View that is been binded to the content control. Here is the code?

The problem is when DyncmicContentControl gets a ViewModel it calls GetTemplate() method to get the corresponding DataTemplate from App.xaml.cs Which creates a new instance of that View but I am not able to pass this ViewModel to that View. How can I achieve this??

**ContentControl.cs**

```
public class DynamicContentControl : ContentControl
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the value of the <see cref="P:System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content" /> property changes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="oldContent">The old value of the <see cref="P:System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content" /> property.</param>
        /// <param name="newContent">The new value of the <see cref="P:System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content" /> property.</param>
        protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
        {
            if (newContent != null)
            {
                base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);
                this.ContentTemplate = DataTemplateSelector.GetTemplate(newContent);
            }
        }
    }
```

**DataTemplateSelector.cs**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the template.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="param">The parameter.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DataTemplate GetTemplate(object param)
    {
        Type t = param.GetType();

        DataTemplate templateData = App.Current.Resources[t.Name] as DataTemplate;

        return templateData;
    }
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
    <Controls:DynamicContentControl Content="{Binding UsrCntrlDynamic}" />
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
 public static ObservableCollection<object> ContentControlItems;
 public MainPageViewModel()
 {
     ContentControlItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();
     ContentControlItems.Add(new UserControlViewModel());
 }
```

**App.xaml**

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="UserControlViewModel">
       <vm:UserControlView />
 </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DataTemplate` set on a `ContentControl`'s `ContentTemplate` property is applied to the object that is set on that `ContentControl`'s `Content` property. So in this case setting the `ContentTemplate` should render that `DataTemplate` with whatever is in the `UsrCntrlDynamic` property that you're binding to. This assumes that the `ControlTemplate` for your `ContentControl` is set up properly, including a `ContentPresenter` to receive and render the `Content`, which may not be the case with your custom `DynamicContentControl`.

Comment: So What is the solution can you suggest a solution for the same. I am trying very hard to get the answers but unable to solve it

Comment: Start by finding the ControlTemplate that is being used to display your control. If you don't know you can try creating one and applying it explicitly as a starting point.

Comment: Could please elaborate. Do you mean that I should try to find parent of the UsrCntrlDyncmic User control parent and go up the VisualTree and then try to derive the ViewModel?